# Lags in Libvirt 5.9.0

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I am using Arch Linux 5.3.13-arch1-1 and libvirt 5.9.0.

After I made a linux update (sudo pacman -Syu), I got the new, libvirt version mentioned above.

But soon after I realized, while programming in Eclipse, that copy paste does not work anymore. After couple of tries, when I try to copy some lines of code, it freezes for a short time, and looses the copied text in the clipboard.

I converted the VMs into vdi and continuing to work with Virtual Box. There, on the same laptop and the same VM, I don't have that issue!

Is this a known issue? I've got other VMs which are optimized for KVM.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you reboot after the upgrade? Mismatching versions of loaded kernel and installed modules may lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Yes I did. The issue could also be QEMU related.